# Loop through irregular enumeration in Delphi

Tags: delphi, loops, enumeration

1) Does anyone know if it is possible to loop through an irregular enumeration in Delphi (XE)?

Looping over a normal enumeration is ok. From [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=For):

```
var
  suit : (Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, Spades);
begin
// Loop 3 times
For suit := Hearts to Diamonds do
   ShowMessage('Suit = '+IntToStr(Ord(suit)));
end;
```

But, if 'suit' instead is declared as

```
var
  suit : (Hearts=1, Clubs, Diamonds=10, Spades);
```

it loops 10 times. Not suprising, but I would like to loop 3. The only solution I've found so far is converting an enumeration to a set and use the 'for ... in'-loop like on [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/for_in_set.htm).

So, if answer to question 1) is no, then:
2) How to convert from enumeration to set in Delphi?

The context I am using it in is a component array of edit-boxes (TEdit) that has an irregular numbering (edit1, edit5, edit7, edit3, ...). While it is possible to reorder all the edit-boxes, it removes the reason of using enumeration as a flexible way to allow addition of an edit-box in the middle of the enumeration.

Comment: Why can't you use some `TList` descendant and iterate over that?

Comment: The enumeration will be used as an index in arrays of TLabels, TEdits and Strings so that I can use StringArray[Job] := Editbox[Job]. TList might work, but the goal was to make the sourcecode easier to read by using (irregular) enums as indexes - like HashMap in Java. Which I see now will probably not work...

Comment: Have you tried to use XEs RTTI?

The ordinary RTTI from unit `TypInfo` fails miserably. Apparently you can not get `TypeInfo()` on a irregular enumeration, I also tried with a set and the gave me access violations.

Comment: I have just recently started using Delphi XE (and Delphi) and have not digged into RTTI. Just used it for converting an Enum to a String: GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TparameterList)), but that was a regular Enum.

Comment: Great! By the way impressed of how Stackoverflow works in terms of helping developers solving issues. Posted issue today, and solved today :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not have a Delphi compiler at hand right now, but I tink that gabr's approach can be rather significantly improved by doing

```
type
  TSuit = (Hearts = 1, Clubs, Diamonds = 10, Spades);

const
  Suits: array[0..3] of TSuit = (Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, Spades);
```

Who knows, maybe it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Tested this and it works! Thanks. If anyone knows if it is possible to avoid repeating the enumeration-list I would be glad to know.

Answer (score 3):

```
type
  TSuit = (Hearts=1, Clubs, Diamonds=10, Spades);

var
  suit: TSuit;
  suitEnum: array [1..4] of TSuit;

//initialization
suitEnum[1] := Hearts;
suitEnum[2] := Clubs;
suitEnum[3] := Diamonds;
suitEnum[4] := Spades;

for suit in suitEnum do
  DoSomething(suit);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since I have around 30 elements in my enum I was hoping to avoid manual initialization. But if there are no shortcuts, I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

I always use

```
var
  s: TSuit;
begin
  for s := Low(TSuit) to High(TSuit) do
    {something};
end;
```

Comment: That works fine if the enumeration is regular, i.e. consecutive numbers, however the key here was **nonconsecutive** enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Loop using Ord(Hearts) to Ord(Spades) ?

Comment: I think Ord(Hearts) to Ord(Spades) will loop 11 times, and not 3 as I want.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty option, useful for small enumerations:

```
type
  TSuit = (Hearts = 1, Clubs, Diamonds = 10, Spades);
var
  Suit: TSuit;
begin
  for Suit in [Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds] do
    WriteLn(Ord(Suit));
```

Works nice in Delphi 2007. Don't know about older versions. Be aware, using `for Suit in [Hearts..Diamonds] do` has the same problem as your loop.
Btw, I use `WriteLn()` because I tested this in a console application. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind. However, since this case have around 30 elements I will use the const-approach suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, even with 30 elements, you should still be able to copy/paste the range from it's original declaration and assign the set to some constant that you re-use for all your loops. It has an added bonus: you can skip elements between the start- and end-element.

Answer (score 0):

It should be understood (and often isn't) that the moment you put hard ordinal assignments into an enumeration, it ceases for all intents to be a Pascalian enumerated type - it just becomes a "bag of constants", which is not the same thing.  This is what C-programmers call enumerations.  However, a Pascalian enumerated type is ORDINAL in all criterion:  It has discrete consecutive values that respond meaningfully to the base operations ORD, PRED, SUCC.  Enumerations in C don't do this, and neither do enums in Pascal once you force the ordinals apart.

THIS is the reason that Delphi's RTTI basically refuses to return type information once this has been done.  To all intents the type is essentially a tkUnknown, and has to be treated as a 'bag' of compile-time constants.  It is only because it still plays lip service to being an ordinal and has (sometimes shaky) support for use in sets that people are led into believing it should still behave like a proper enumerated type.  It's better to just understand it for what it really is:  a nod to enumerated values in C.  Avoid mixing the coding metaphor!

If you do this, then your solution becomes obvious:  you use an enumerated type (a proper one) to index a corresponding array of CONSTANTS.  Then you can make the ordinals whatever you want, and the enums retain their full RTTI definitions as a proper enumeration.  So:  your ENUMERATED TYPE contains proper unchanged ordinal values.  You get your funny numbers by indexing the constants array using the enumeration -ergo  array [MyEnums] of byte = (1,3,8,22,99,whatever)