# Iterate throught enum type with constant assigned and get its name

Tags: delphi, rtti

For normal enums I can do loop through and get all names:

```
type
  TMyEnum = (apple, pear, plum);

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: TMyEnum;
  s: String;
begin
  s:= '';
  for I := Low(TMyEnum) to High(TMyEnum) do
  begin
    s := s + TRttiEnumerationType.GetName<TMyEnum>(i) + sLineBreak;
  end;
  ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

But, for:

```
TMyEnum = (apple=5, pear=20, plum=70);
```

1. How to iterate through this?
2. How to get the names through RTTI?

Comment: yes, without constants assigned it is ok but with constant it raise error [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(41): E2134 Type 'TMyEnum' has no type info

Comment: Known limitation: enum declarations with constants don't get RTTI. Probably best to use a conversion array here:

Answer (score 3):

Enumeration types declared with constant values don't get RTTI, so this way it cannot work. Depending on your requirements this might be an alternative:

```
type
  TMyEnum = (apple, pear, plum);

  TMyEnumHelper = record helper for TMyEnum
  private const
    cEnumInt: array[TMyEnum] of Integer = (5, 20, 70);
  public
    function GetAsInteger: Integer;
    procedure SetAsInteger(const Value: Integer);
    property AsInteger: Integer read GetAsInteger write SetAsInteger;
  end;

function TMyEnumHelper.GetAsInteger: Integer;
begin
  Result := cEnumInt[Self];
end;

procedure TMyEnumHelper.SetAsInteger(const Value: Integer);
var
  I: TMyEnum;
begin
  for I := Low(cEnumInt) to High(cEnumInt) do begin
    if cEnumInt[I] = Value then begin
      Self := I;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  raise ERangeError.Create('not a valid enum value');
end;
```

Comment: See [Loop through irregular enumeration in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4132717/576719)

Comment: I suppose that answer in that link is the best in scenario of lack of this functionality in Delphi itself